# Why is `p1.name BETWEEN 'a' AND 'az'` skipping over names that start with "Aztec"

Tags: mysql

I'm quite confused with these two SQL queries I'm not getting the same results where, there are several records missing.

The `LIKE` query returns the actual number of items `107` (See [JSON file](https://pastebin.com/W2RNjkwZ))

**WHERE**

```
(p1.name LIKE "A%")
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT p1.id, 
  p1.name, 
  p1.code, 
  p1.date_updated, 
  name AS name_full, 
  p1.price, 
  p1.price_special 
FROM 
  product AS p1 
WHERE 
  (p1.name LIKE "A%") 
GROUP BY 
  p1.id 
ORDER BY 
  name_full ASC
```

The `BETWEEN` query, returns `97` (This is suppose to return everything from `a-z`, starting with `a`) (see [JSON file](https://pastebin.com/ThSLj1Bx))

**WHERE**

```
p1.name BETWEEN 'a' AND 'az'
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT 
  p1.id, 
  p1.name, 
  p1.code, 
  p1.date_updated, 
  name AS name_full, 
  p1.price, 
  p1.price_special 
FROM 
  product AS p1 
WHERE 
  (
    p1.name BETWEEN 'a' 
    AND 'az'
  ) 
GROUP BY 
  p1.id 
ORDER BY 
  name_full
```

**Missing DATA**

```
"Aztec Fanged God Mould",
"Aztec God of Fate Mould",
"Aztec Goddess of Rivers Mould",
"Aztec Head Planter Large Mould",
"Aztec Head Planter Small Mould",
"Aztec Queen Mould",
"Aztec River Goddess",
"Aztec Stone Mask Mould",
"Aztec Toltec God Mould",
"Aztec Xiutec Planter Mould"
```

My question is why would the `p1.name BETWEEN 'a' AND 'az'` be skipping every `Aztec` row (but allowing words such as `Abstract`, `African`, `Alligator` and so on), when the `name` both starts with `a` (and is not limited by alphabet)?

The only difference I can see is that `Aztec` starts with `AZ`

Comment: `Aztec` starts with `A`, not `a`. Look at the ASCII table.

Comment: That doesn't explain `Aztec` missing when it becomes `LOWER(p1.name) BETWEEN 'a' AND 'az'`, it also doesn't explain why the word `Abstract Elephant Mould` would be in the JSON LIST (Given that `name` also starts with `A` and not `a`)
`

Comment: This compare is collation-dependent. You use case-sensitive collation, hence `'A' < 'a'`. Specify case-insensitive collation explicitly, like `p1.name COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci BETWEEN 'a' AND 'az'`.

Comment: `"Aztec Fanged God Mould"` is **NOT** `BETWEEN 'a' AND 'az'` in any std. collation... use, for example, `BETWEEN 'a' AND 'azz'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` comes before any string starting with `A`, such as `Az` and `Aztec`.

By the same logic, `Az` comes before any string starting with `Az`, such as `Aztec`.

Here are ways to look for words beginning with `A`:

```
WHERE col >= 'A' AND col < 'B'  -- but this assumes that B comes immediately after A
```

Contrast:

```
WHERE col BETWEEN 'a' AND 'az'
WHERE col BETWEEN 'a' AND 'azzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'
```

`BETWEEN` is "inclusive".  That is it includes both 'a' but nothing before 'a'; also 'az' (or 'azzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'), but nothing after it.

This is a gotcha for `DATE` versus `DATETIME`:

```
BETWEEN '2021-02-03' AND '2021-04-05'
```

includes midnight of the morning of '2021-04-05', but *no* other times during that day.  (such as one second later: '2021-04-05 00:00:01')

```
WHERE col LIKE 'A%'  -- This is simple and straightforward

WHERE col REGEXP '^A'  -- Cryptic until you understand regexps.
```

Comment: Is there anyway to improve `WHERE col BETWEEN 'a' AND 'az'` so it can include something like `Aztec` ???

Comment: @classicjonesynz - Please elaborate on why it needs improving.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `SELECT SUBSTRING(p1.name,1,1) AS p1FirstLetter` (or preferred variable name)

and use

`WHERE p1FirstLetter = 'a' Or p1FirstLetter = 'A'`

Or, more simply (and without extra columns):

`WHERE (SUBSTRING(p1.name,1,1) = 'a') Or (SUBSTRING(p1.name,1,1) = 'A')`

Essentially, each character you add to a string adds value. While `'az' <= 'az'` is true, `'aza' > 'az'` because the additional character adds additional value. You would have to compare to `'azzzzzzz...'` with the number of `z`s being one less than the length of your `p1.name` for your method to work.

Answer (score 1):

`BETWEEN` does not auto-extend your strings for you.

`a` and `az` and even `Az` will never retrun `Aztec`. The function is better suited for numbers (int, float, ...) and dates because the system knows how to compare them as they are limited in length.

String values can vary. If you were to use `BETWEEN` you would have to compare like this to receive the `Aztec ....`  values from your data:

```
SELECT 
  p1.id, 
  p1.name, 
  p1.code, 
  p1.date_updated, 
  name AS name_full, 
  p1.price, 
  p1.price_special 
FROM 
  product AS p1 
WHERE 
  (
    p1.name BETWEEN 'A' 
    -- Because `A` is before `a` in the ASCII character table
    AND CONCAT('a', REPEAT('z',255) 
    -- where 255is the length of the maximum length of data -1 for the first `a`
  ) 
GROUP BY 
  p1.id 
ORDER BY 
  name_full
```